# How can I return 2 int values from a function

Tags: c, function, return, return-value

I need to return 2 values from 2 diffent functions. One of the values come from scanf(closedinterval()) and the other is made inside the function(rootinquad()). Is there a simple way to return these values?

```
#include <math.h>
#include <stdio.h>
int rootinquad()
{
    double a, b, c, discriminant, root1, root2, realPart, imagPart;
    printf("Enter coefficients a, b and c: ");
    scanf("%lf %lf %lf", &a, &b, &c);
    discriminant = b * b - 4 * a * c;
    if (discriminant > 0) {
        root1 = (-b + sqrt(discriminant)) / (2 * a);
        root2 = (-b - sqrt(discriminant)) / (2 * a);
    }
    else if (discriminant == 0) {
        root1 = root2 = -b / (2 * a);
    }
    else {
        realPart = -b / (2 * a);
        imagPart = sqrt(-discriminant) / (2 * a);
    }
    return root1,root2;
} 
int closedinterval()
{
    int root1, root2,i=1;
    printf("Closed interval: ");
    scanf("%d%d", &root1, &root2);
    return root1,root2;
}
int main()
{
    int root1, root2;
    char ka;
    printf("Is there a closed interval in the question?(y/n) ");
    scanf(" %c", &ka);
    switch(ka)
    {
    case 'y':
    closedinterval();
    break;
    case 'n':
    rootinquad();
    break;
    default:
    printf("answer the question");
    break;
    }
    printf("%d%d",root1,root2);//test
    return 0;
}
```

I tried root1=closedinterval() but it works for only 1 value and I cant think of ways to return root2 without it being long and boring.

Comment: you can return pointer to a struct or to an int array. but do not allocate these on the stack, use malloc() instead

Comment: In C it is fine to return a small struct by value. No need for pointers.

Comment: A common convention is to pass two integer pointers: `void closedinterval(int *proot1, int *proot2)`. Call the function using `closedinterval(&root1, &root2);`.

Comment: You're coding in C ... get used to some things being "long and boring" (although imo this isn't one of them). You'll probably start feeling better about it as you learn some more advanced techniques

Answer (score 3, accepted):

use a struct

```
typedef struct roots {
    double root1, root2;
} roots_t;

roots_t solve(double a, double b, double c) {
    roots_t result;
    result.root1 = 0;
    result.root2 = 1;
    return result;
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    roots_t s = solve(1,2,3);
    printf("result: %f %f", s.root1, s.root2);
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do this by passing your variables by address:

```
#include <stdio.h>

void closedinterval(int *root1, int *root2)
{
    printf("Closed interval: ");
    scanf("%d%d", root1, root2);
}

int main()
{
    int root1, root2;

    closedinterval(&root1, &root2);

    printf("%d - %d",root1,root2);//test
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Thanks it works but I dont understand why it doesnt when I use & inside the scanf value.

Comment: If you changed your code per the above answer, it sounds like you’re still calling `scanf("%d%d", &root1, &root2);`, meaning you’re passing ‘int **` arguments to `scanf`. Remove the `&` operators.

Comment: @OnurAlp that's because `root1` and `root2` are already pointers to `int` and that's what `scanf() expects